# Laravel: Combine dynamic scope and with

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to eager load a dynamic scope in Laravel 4.2

I have the following Eloquent class:

```
class Project extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'projects';

    public function subProjects() {
        return $this->hasMany('SubProject');
    }
}
```

On the `Subproject` class, I have the following dynamic scope:

```
public function scopeForUserInPeriod($query, $user, $interval) {
  return $query->whereHas('hourRegistrations', function($query) use($user, $interval) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user->id)->whereBetween('date', [$interval->from, $interval->to]);
  });
}
```

Now I would like to eagerload the scope when I load my projects, so I do something like.

```
Project::with('SubProjects.ForUserInPeriod', $user, $period);
```

Unfortunately, `with` only accepts a list of relations to load. I can't seem to find any indications whatsoever on how I am supposed to eagerload scopes that take arguments. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass anything else but relations when eager/lazy loading.

You use dots to indicate nested relations, not methods on the query.

This is what you want:

```
Project::with(['subProjects' => function ($q) use ($user, $period) {
 $q->forUserInPeriod($user, $period);
}])->get();
```